# NSLog not showing after reopening app from the device

Tags: ios, xcode, nslog

I have an iPhone connected to Xcode. I have a `NSLog(@"test")` on the main page. When I build (run) my app from Xcode I see it's printing `test` on debugging area.

Then ... I close my app (terminate it) **from the device screen** and then **relaunch it from the device screen** and **it doesn't print** `test` again (provided that device stays usb-connected at all time)... NSLog gets disabled when app is terminated and relaunched from the device.

How to make NSLog active all the time as long as device is usb-connected?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

When you close the app, it is disconnected from the debugger. To connect it to the debugger again, you would have to launch it from Xcode again. You can still view the console directly though. Go to  Window > Devices > (Select device) > tap the arrow at the bottom to slide up the console.

Comment: Well... I guess it's the only option (not as convenient though, cuz it's constantly printing some other stuff).